# Debug simple c code, double linked list copy

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list

[my files are here(link removed)]

My copy function doesn't copy the whole list.

As required by @Mat, here is the "copy" function, but you still need to read the rest of the file to understand my struct.

```
Line copyLineText(Line l){
  Line newl = malloc (sizeof( struct node ));
  checkMalloc(newl,"copyLineText");
  newl->length = l->length;
  newl->buffer = malloc((newl->length)* sizeof(char));
  checkMalloc(newl->buffer,"copyLineText buffer");
  strncpy(newl->buffer, l->buffer, newl->length);
  return newl;
}
/* Copy the lines between and including 'from' and 'to' of the textbuffer
 * 'tb'.
 *
 * - The result is a new textbuffer (much as one created with newTB()).
 * - The textbuffer 'tb' will remain unmodified.
 * - The program is to abort() with an error message if 'from' or 'to' is out
 *   of range. 
 */
TB copyTB (TB tb, int from, int to){
    if (from > to || from < 0 || to >= tb->numLines){
        printf("Error: the from to is out of range\n");
        abort();
    }
    Line line = tb->begin;
    while(line->linePosition != from){
        line = line->next;
    }

    TB tbCopy = malloc (sizeof( struct textbuffer ));

    Line last = NULL, curr = line, currCopy;

    while( curr != NULL && (curr->linePosition != to + 1) ){
        currCopy = copyLineText(curr);

        if(last == NULL){
          tbCopy->begin  = currCopy;
        }
        currCopy->prev = last;
        if(last != NULL){
            last->next = currCopy;
            //printf("362debug: last->next = currCopy\n");
        }
        last = curr;
        //printf("364debug: %d\n",curr->linePosition);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

        currCopy->next = NULL;
        tbCopy->end  = currCopy;
        tbCopy->numLines  = to - from + 1;
        return tbCopy;
}
```

If you run my code, you'll see:

```
tb2:2 lines
abcde
fg


tb2copy:2 lines
abcde
```

With this simple test, the copy produced by my function has one line less than the original structure.

Comment: please post the relevant parts of the code (structure definitions and the copy routine), and an example of what "doesn't copy the whole list" means.

Comment: Does whatever a `TB` points to and a `struct textbuffer` occupy the same number of bytes of memory?

Comment: Don't hide pointerness of identifiers in a typedef.

Comment: @pmg - "pointerness." I like that; good word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 161 in question.c, while you're copying your linked list, you're assigning elements from the *original* linked list to `last`, instead of assigning the previous one from the *newly* created list.

Change that line from:

```
last = curr;
```

to:

```
last = currCopy;
```